# EC2 server suddenly got rebooted

Tags: amazon-ec2

```
reboot   system boot  3.9.30-11.41.amz Thu Oct 12 18:33 - 10:06  (15:33)
```

I got this log and I realize my aws is rebooted during this time. What happens? What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Anything important just before that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Werner Vogels: “Everything fails all the time”**

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/

> Customers are expected to build resilience into their applications. We recommend using databases and file systems that support redundancy and fault tolerance. Customers should back up data periodically to Amazon S3 for improved data durability.

AWS is a hosting company like any hosting it has hardware failures. EBS volumes will fail, instances will fail. It is up to the customer to build high availability and resilience into their application/servers. AWS has a lot of great services that help in that endeavor. Like [Auto recovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html), [Auto scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/), and [Elastic load balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). Implementing those will help with building a resilient application in AWS.

You can track status of services here

http://status.aws.amazon.com/

To be alerted with issues with your EC2 instances you can setup Cloud watch Alarms 
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/